# import tensorflow working in terminal but not in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, conda, environment

I used the following guide to install tensorflow-gpu - https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc

I created a new environment and installed tensorflow-gpu using the command -

> conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu

If I activate the environment, start python in terminal, and import tensorflow from the terminal, it works.

BUT

When I activate the environment, run a jupyter notebook and type -

> import tensorflow

I get module not found error. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Start Command Promt (CMD) as administrator (right click). Do not enter any environment yet.
2. Install Jupyter (and nb_conda as well as ipykernel) to get your environments listed: conda install jupyter nb_conda ipykernel
3. Activate the environment you want to add to jupyter kernel: conda activate myenv
4. Install ipykernel in the environment (do this for all envvironemnts you would like to add): conda install ipykernel
5. To start Jupyter, cd to root (cd .. until you are at C:) then type (does not need to be inside and env): Jupyter noteboook
6. You might need to confirm that it shall open in a web browser (I use chrome)
   Once open in a browser navigate to the folder of your choice, then make a new python 3 file.
7. Once inside click Kernel -> Change kernel and select the conda env you would like

You should now be able to change kernel (env) within all conda environments that have ipykernel installed (step 4)

Comment: Thank a lot for the answer! I had just arrived at the same solution after an hour of digging. In case someone comes across this post, I'm adding this link for further clarification of your answer - https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1524