# TensorFlow GPU recognized in the terminal but not in the Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I installed TensorFlow with the GPU support according to the [official installation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) and GPU is recognized from the terminal but not from the Jupyter notebook with the Jupyter kernel from the same Conda environment `tensor_gpu` (see the screenshot below). The Jupyter Lab 3.6.3 (Windows 10) is installed and run from the separate Conda environment `jupyter`.

[image]

I also see the following warning in the Jupyter Lab console:

```bash
2023-04-25 16:34:44.493879: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2023-04-25 16:34:44.494185: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2023-04-25 16:34:47.012660: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2023-04-25 16:34:47.014859: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2023-04-25 16:34:47.017536: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2023-04-25 16:34:47.019433: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2023-04-25 16:34:47.021223: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2023-04-25 16:34:47.023012: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2023-04-25 16:34:47.024836: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2023-04-25 16:34:47.026672: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2023-04-25 16:34:47.026872: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

Could you please suggest what I am missing here, like environment variables, additional paths, etc.?

The list of installed packages in the environment `tensor_gpu`:

```bash
(tensor_gpu) C:\Users\Pavlo Fesenko\Desktop>mamba list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Pavlo Fesenko\.conda\envs\tensor_gpu: 
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge    
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge    
backports                 1.0                pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge    
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge    
brotli-bin                1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge    
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39ha55989b_1005    conda-forge  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h8ffe710_4    conda-forge    
ca-certificates           2022.12.7            h5b45459_0    conda-forge    
cachetools                5.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2022.12.7                pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.15.1           py39h68f70e3_3    conda-forge    
charset-normalizer        3.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge    
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge    
comm                      0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge    
contourpy                 1.0.7            py39h1f6ef14_0    conda-forge    
cryptography              40.0.2           py39hb6bd5e6_0    conda-forge    
cudatoolkit               11.2.2              h7d7167e_11    conda-forge    
cudnn                     8.1.0.77             h3e0f4f4_0    conda-forge    
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge    
debugpy                   1.6.7            py39h99910a6_0    conda-forge    
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge    
executing                 1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge    
flatbuffers               23.3.3                   pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.39.3           py39ha55989b_0    conda-forge    
freetype                  2.12.1               h546665d_1    conda-forge    
gast                      0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gettext                   0.21.1               h5728263_0    conda-forge
glib                      2.76.2               h12be248_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.76.2               h12be248_0    conda-forge
google-auth               2.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.54.0                   pypi_0    pypi
gst-plugins-base          1.22.0               h001b923_2    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.22.0               h6b5321d_2    conda-forge
h5py                      3.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
icu                       72.1                 h63175ca_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        6.6.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib-resources       5.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        6.6.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       5.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         h57928b3_46319    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.22.0             pyh025b116_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.12.0             pyh08f2357_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.3.0            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
keras                     2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.4            py39h1f6ef14_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.20.1               heb0366b_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.15                 h3e3b177_1    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              16_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                hcfcfb64_8    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              16_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libclang                  16.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
libclang13                16.0.2          default_h45d3cf4_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.18                 hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h8ffe710_5    conda-forge
libglib                   2.76.2               he8f3873_0    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.1                h51c2c0f_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
libjpeg-turbo             2.1.5.1              hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              16_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h19919ed_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.40.0               hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.0                h6c8260b_6    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.0                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              hcd874cb_1004    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.10.4               hc3477c8_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hcfcfb64_4    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
markdown                  3.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.7.1            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.7.1            py39haf65ace_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2022.1.0           h6a75c08_874    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.24.3           py39h816b6a6_0    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
openjpeg                  2.5.0                ha2aaf27_2    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.0                hcfcfb64_2    conda-forge
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 23.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.0.1            py39h1679cfb_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.40                h17e33f8_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    9.5.0            py39haa1d754_0    conda-forge
pip                       23.1.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ply                       3.11                       py_1    conda-forge
pooch                     1.7.0              pyha770c72_3    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.38             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.38               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.19.6                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.5            py39ha55989b_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               hcd874cb_1001    conda-forge
pthreads-win32            2.9.1                hfa6e2cd_3    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.15.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 23.1.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.15.7           py39hb77abff_3    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0          py39h99910a6_3    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyh0701188_6    conda-forge
python                    3.9.16          h4de0772_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.9                      3_cp39    conda-forge
pytz                      2023.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   304              py39h99910a6_2    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.0.2           py39hea35a22_0    conda-forge
qt-main                   5.15.8               h7f2b912_9    conda-forge
requests                  2.28.2             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.9                      pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.10.1           py39hde5eda1_0    conda-forge
setuptools                67.7.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sip                       6.7.9            py39h99910a6_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.9.0             h91493d7_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.31.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tomli                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.3              py39ha55989b_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.5.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.5.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h71feb2d_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              15.0.0           py39ha55989b_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.15            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.3                hb6edc58_10    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.34.31931         h4c5c07a_10    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.40.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_6    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h8d14728_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h0e60522_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.15.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                h12be248_6    conda-forge
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided in this same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332001/import-tensorflow-working-in-terminal-but-not-in-jupyter-notebook)?

Comment: @LaassairiAbdellah My case is different, I can import TensorFlow in the notebook without problems (as shown on the screenshot) but somehow it doesn't recognize GPU. I feel that some environment variables for CUDA toolkit or cuDNN might be missing but not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the pytorch environment, the python file normally calls the GPU, but jupyter cannot call the GPU

Solution:

The first step is to view the previous kernel location

jupyter kernelspec list

The second step is to delete the previous kernel

jupyter kernelspec remove 'your kernel name'

I am here jupyter kernelspec remove python3

The third step is to install the nb_conda_kernels in base environment package to automatically generate the kernel from python in the virtual environment

conda install nb_conda_kernels

Wait for the installation to complete

The test successfully calls cuda

Comment: I am launching JupyterLab from a separate environment so I installed nb_conda_kernels there and it worked! 